# How to save an edited .conllu file using conllu python library

Tags: nlp, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

I want to ask something that perhaps I cannot find yet in the internet.

First of all I'm using the Universal Dependencies dataset and want to edit some data on Jupyter Notebook (python 3.6).

I found the conllu library https://pypi.org/project/conllu/ and use it to work with .conllu UD dataset. I want to edit one of the data (like changing the lemma). Here's the example:
[image: Example]

I've read there's a function in conllu library

> .serialize()

that could change back the format to .conllu format instead of string.

But I think it won't save the actual file, it just print it.

All I want is the actual file changed.
Anyone can help me, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

conllu does not handle this at the sentence level. You would have to go through every TokenList, serialize it, and append it to a file or append to a string which you then write to a file.

An alternative to conllu, [pyconll](https://github.com/pyconll/pyconll), would be able to handle this easier (if not using iteration, otherwise it is the same), as such.

```
conll = pyconll.load_from_file("mytreebank.conllu")
for sentence in conll:
    # Your custom work and changes here

conll.write("mynew.conllu")
```

For solving the issue with conllu, something like this would work:

```
with open("mynew.conllu", "w") as f:
    for token_list in parse_incr(ud_data):
        # Your custom work and changes here
        serialized = token_list.serialize()
        f.write(serialized)
        f.write('\n\n')
```

Disclaimer: I am the creator of pyconll.